# Azure Functions Powershell Module Import

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am not able to have the AzuedAD module to run in Azure Functions it gives the below warning and error. It works on the local machine but not in the Azure functions app
It is running on the serverless plan

```
2021-05-23T04:37:44.334 [Warning] WARNING: Module AzureAD is loaded in Windows PowerShell using WinPSCompatSession remoting session; please note that all input and output of commands from this module will be deserialized objects. If you want to load this module into PowerShell Core please use 'Import-Module -SkipEditionCheck' syntax.
```

The syntax  for  'Import-Module -SkipEditionCheck' = ?

**Requirements.Psd1**

```
#
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. Uncomment the next line and replace the MAJOR_VERSION, e.g., 'Az' = '5.*'
    'Az' = '4.1.0'
    'AzureAD' = '2.0.2.135'
}
```

**host.json**
The ManagedDependency has an issue stating that  *

> "Property managedDependency is not allowed."

- 

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "managedDependency": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

****The Code** run.ps1**

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)


Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell  
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
#[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3
$Username =
$Password=  | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password) 
Connect-AzureAD  -Credential $Credential | Out-Null

$list = Get-AzureADGroupMember  -ObjectId 123456



# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value (
    [HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $list
}
)
```

Comment: have you verified if its intalled using Kudu?

Comment: @Sajeetharan
These are the below files it shows in the root folder. The requirements.psd1 should   handle the installation part ?                      
d----        5/21/2021  11:07 AM                PS_HTTP                       
---       5/21/2021  11:07 AM             41 .funcignore                   
---       5/21/2021   6:29 PM            339 host.json                     
---     5/21/2021   5:59 PM            897 profile.ps1                   
---     5/21/2021  11:07 AM             72 proxies.json                  
--      5/23/2021   9:53 AM            376 requirements.psd1

Comment: Have you tried `Import-Module -Name AzureAD -SkipEditionCheck` ?

Comment: @Eric The warning you are observing is expected: modules imported with `-UseWindowsPowerShell` are loaded into a separate process, and the warning simply explains the consequences. Using `-SkipEditionCheck` may not help, as the AzureAD module was designed for **Windows** PowerShell, and it may not properly work in PowerShell **Core** (depending on the functionality you need), but it mostly works fine in the compatibility mode (`-UseWindowsPowerShell`). Do you experience any other problem with this module besides this expected warning?

Comment: @AnatoliBeliaev
Create PS cred with usr and pwd fails

I get the below error with Authentication failed. The same script works on the local machine when published to PowerShell Func it fails. 

[Error] ERROR: One or more errors occurred.: An error occurred while sending the request.OriginInfo            : localhostException             :Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteExceptionSerializedRemoteException      : Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadAuthenticationFailedException: One or more errors occurred.: An error occurred while sending the request.

Comment: @Thomas
I tried various combinations of  
Import-Module -Name AzureAD -SkipEditionCheck

It states the   -SkipEditionCheck parameter does not exist

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [Target Specific versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#target-specific-versions) of modules, use a command like below:

```
Import-Module <Module> -RequiredVersion '2.0.2.135'
```

I think that might be the issue as the doc says `you also need to add an import statement to the top of your ps1 file`

Comment: Since my  Azure function will have an HTTP trigger and input passed I cannot add the import-module statement at the top of the .ps1 script as it will fail with param not found error
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Comment: It should not be an issue, pls check out the documentation shared above. This statement is part of `profile.ps1` file. If this answer helps you, pls mark it as an answer to help other community members

Comment: Can you mark above response as an answer if it helped you?